# Operating 12v Solenoid with Rpi4 and IO Pi Plus

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I am a noob, trying to operate a 12v Solenoid with Rpi4 + IOPiPlus + 12v Relay. Took the [Blinking LED](https://www.abelectronics.co.uk/kb/article/17/io-pi-plus-tutorial-1-the-blinking-led) sample code and used it as-is for the 12v Solenoid. Quickly figured out I will need help, as the code does not seem to do anything. Appreciate any and all guidance.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from IOPi import IOPi
import time
bus = IOPi(0x21)

# setting the pins as outputs
bus.set_port_direction(0, 0x00)

# turn off all pins on port 0
bus.write_port(0, 0x00)

while True:
    bus.write_pin(1, 1)
    time.sleep(1)
    bus.write_pin(1, 0)
    time.sleep(1)*
```

[image]

Comment: You'll probably have more luck asking this question on the rPi stack exchange
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/